# How to get users order by last activity

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

i have a table named "users" and another table named "activities",
how can i get users order by last activity from "activities" table ?

using query builder.
one user has many activities, like login,logout,add product, sell product, etc.
Thank you.

Comment: Why not use model relationships?

Comment: Can you show us the tables with their columns? There is little to see at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your column names are specified as, something like this could work:

```
$users = \DB::table('users')
->join('activities', 'activities.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
->orderBy('activities.created_at', 'desc')
->get();
```

Comment: @Zen still cant what?